# Using VLookup macro to return a text value from a set range of numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I have converted a Vlookup formula in a macro in order to avoid filling out the cell with the formula content. The following code worked only with a table with fixed number:

```
Sub NumberVLookup()

Dim num As Long
num = 4

Set shData = Sheet2
Dim sRes As Variant
sRes = Application.VLookup( _
              num, shData.Range("A1:B6"), 2, True)

Debug.Print sRes
Sheet2.Range("C4") = sRes
End Sub
```

Instead I would like to create a code that gives me more flexibility in the way
it returns its text values by using VLookup function. 
For example I would like that all numbers included in the range between:
0-9 return text value Red
10-15 return text value Yellow
16-20 return text value Green

The table to which I am referring to is the following:

```
     A          B    
 1  0-9        Red 
 2  10-15     Yellow   
 3  16-20     Green
```

For example if the value is 4 the VLookup macro will return text value "Red".
I hope the question is enough clear. Many thanks

Comment: if you use values 0,10, and 15 in column A, your vlookup will automatically fill the missing pieces.

Comment: @nutsch - D'oh! That's pretty clever, I've not thought of that before. I always did a (now seemingly unnecessary) range table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a range, with a non-Exact match.

Set up the data in three columns, with your ranges on the left in Ascending order.

Then use

```
=VLOOKUP(A7,$A$2:$C$4,3,TRUE)
```

Assuming your data is like this:

[image]

So for VBA (adjust as necessary):

```
 Application.VLookup(num, shData.Range("$A$2:$C$4"), 3, True)
```

Edit: Or you can just follow @nutsch's great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub NumberVLookup()

 Dim num As Long
 num = 16


 Dim sRes As Variant
 sRes = Application.VLookup( _
          num, Sheet2.Range("A56:B58"), 2, True)

Debug.Print sRes
Sheet2.Range("J15") = sRes
End Sub
```